# Wait for an Actor to exit()

Tags: unit-testing, scala, concurrency, actor

How do I wait for a Scala Actor to exit()?  I set up two Actors in a unit test, and send a few messages to get them started.  They send a few messages back and forth and eventually both call exit().  How do I make my unit test wait for both Actors to finish up before passing?

Answer (score 7):

If you know in advance the number of messages exchanged between the actors, you can use a `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` to keep track of the count of messages. In the actors, after each processing of the message, do

```
latch.countDown()
```

and in your main thread do

```
latch.await()
```

This will make your main thread wait till the count of the latch is down to zero.

If you don't know the count of the messages in advance, but have a condition which indicates the finish, then you can use `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`. In the actors, when your condition is satisfied, do

```
if (conditionSatisfied)
  condition.signal()
```

and in your main thread do

```
while (!conditionSatisfied)
 condition.await()
```

to make it wait till the condition is satisfied.

See the javadocs of [`CountDownLatch`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and [`Condition`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) for details.

See [this Gist](http://gist.github.com/403073) for example of using `Condition`.

Comment: I could countDown() just before exit() and only count to 1.  That seems redundant though since the two methods would always be called together.

Comment: I don't get it. You want the main thread to wait till the actors are finished, right? That is what the `await()` calls will do.

Comment: It means I have to add a latch or condition to the production code (the actors) purely for a JUnit test (waiting on the Actors).

Comment: wrap your _production_ actors with _unit test_ delegate actors which have latch or condition.

Comment: I faced this today, and used one CountDownLatch that is released prior to the 'exit' in the actor. Just outside the actor body (I'm using 'actor{...}', not inheritance) I do the await. While it's peculiar that there is no API in the Actor object for this, it was easy to do. The reason I do this? The outer calls are sequential, but inside a certain function I use parallelism (actors). Before returning from the function I need to make sure all work has been done.

Answer (score 2):

In Specs you can use [Eventually Matchers](http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/MatchersGuide#Eventually_matchers). If you know the final state of your actor or any entity (say, persistence store) it modifies, you may force test to wait, until the switch to this state will occur:

```
<entity state> must eventually(10, 1.second)(be(<state>)) // there will be 10 retires every second, and if the state will be different, exception is thrown
```

Comment: That would make the unit test take about a tenth of a second to run which is way too slow.